# Can't get a form to show in front of another

Tags: vb.net, winforms

On my main form I call

```
        WaitingForm.Show()
        WaitingForm.Focus()
        WaitingForm.Select()
```

and then run work in a backgroundworker. For some reason that form never opens in front of my main form though. How can I get it to show infront?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have instantialized this New Form if it was created programatically. In which case you can use the [Topmost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Property of the Form.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Using topmost will set the form always on top on any other form. no form hierarchy in this.

Comment: @Sievajet that is true. And although I saw your answer and deemed it the most obvious reply, I noticed our OP could also be looking for the TopMost property if he meant not to use hierarchy (there are many reasons not to). Hence my post. I think both replies will remain valid for whomever comes next looking for a solution. For now it seems the Topmost is what our OP was looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Form.Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) property to make a form owned by another form. Assign its Owner property a reference to the form that will be the owner. For example:

```
WaitingForm.Show(Me)
```